# How to toggle li element by clicking first li element in ul list?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, toggle

I am trying to toggle all `li` elements that have `.hassubs-filter` on click. Since I have these lists repeated many times on the page I don't want to add any `id` to them.

I tried to do it with `parent()`, `find()`, and `slideToggle()` however it does not hide/display. Can you help me?

```js
$('.search__filters').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-filter">
  <ul class="mainnav-filter">
    <li class="headtext-filter">
      <a href="#" class="search__filters">
        All Items
        <div class="chevron-down"></div>  
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.search__filters').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('li').siblings('li.hassubs-filter').slideToggle();
});
```

Appreciated, Use above code to show/hide list items on clicking the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM traversal to find the `.hassubs-filter` elements related to the clicked `a` isn't quite right. You can use `closest()` to get the parent `li`, then `siblings(), like this:

```js
$('.search__filters').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').siblings('.hassubs-filter').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-filter">
  <ul class="mainnav-filter">
    <li class="headtext-filter">
      <a href="#" class="search__filters">
        All Items
        <div class="chevron-down"></div>  
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
  </ul>
</div><div class="main-filter">
  <ul class="mainnav-filter">
    <li class="headtext-filter">
      <a href="#" class="search__filters">
        All Items
        <div class="chevron-down"></div>  
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
  </ul>
</div><div class="main-filter">
  <ul class="mainnav-filter">
    <li class="headtext-filter">
      <a href="#" class="search__filters">
        All Items
        <div class="chevron-down"></div>  
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
    <li class="hassubs-filter">Some Text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```